# How to read and plot arrays from pandas df fast

Tags: python, sql, arrays, pandas, matplotlib

I have following data frame in pandas that contains array reading it directly from a sqlite db using pd.read_sql():

```
      ArrayID  Value
 0        0      0
 1        0      1
 2        0      2
 3        0      3
 4        0      4
 5        0      5
 6        1      0
 7        1      1
 8        1      2
 9        1      3
```

I would like to know a fast way to get the arrays so I can plot it:

```
Array0 [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Array1 [0,1,2,3]
```

The only way I could think was (really slow when the table has 1000 arrays with arrays varying on length having maxixum length of 500):

```
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# loop on
for id in df.ArrayID:
    array = df.loc[df["ArrayID"]==id, "Value"].values()
    plt.plot(array)

plt.show()
```

Or is the matplotlib beeing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` to obtain the groups in one call, (instead of many calls to `df.loc` and `df['ArrayID'] == id`):

```
for aid, grp in df.groupby(['ArrayID']):
    plt.plot(grp['Value'].values)
```

---

Note also that `plt.plot` is not very fast. Calling it 1000 times may feel pretty slow. Moreover, a plot with 1000 lines may not look very comprehensible. You may need to rethink the quantity (perhaps through clustering or aggregation) that you wish to visualize.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N, M = 500, 1000
data = np.row_stack([np.column_stack(np.broadcast_arrays(i, 
    (np.random.random(np.random.randint(N))-0.5).cumsum())) for i in range(M)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ArrayID', 'Value'])
for aid, grp in df.groupby(['ArrayID']):
    plt.plot(grp['Value'].values) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it worked well for my task! I just changed plt.plot(grp["Value"]) to plt.plot(grp["Value"].values)  so the x-axis is always starting from 0 for each array. Would you recomend other solution for faster plot in python? I know the amount of line is to high for a plot. But I wonder if it is possible to plot faster in python.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better suggestion, though running the code above didn't seem too terribly slow.